# Why does this JPQL syntax exception occur?

Tags: java, jpa

Exception Error code

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpabook");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
TypedQuery<Member> query = em.createQuery("select m from Member m",Member.class);
List<Member> memberList = query.getResultList();
```

---

Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MEMBER")
public class Member {
    @Id
    @Column(name="MEMBER_ID")
    private String id;
    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String username;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TEAM_ID", referencedColumnName = "TEAM_ID")
    private Team team;

    public Member() {
    }

    public Member(String id, String username) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Member setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public Member setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        return this;
    }

    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public Member setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
        team.getMembers().add(this);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", team=" + team +
                '}';
    }

}
```

---

Exception Message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: Member near line 1, column 15 [select m from Member m]
```

---

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I do not know why this exception occurs because the grammar looks fine.We are using jpa as a team project. But the above problem is only for some team members. I do not know what environment affects such an exception.

I know that Hibernate supports the JPQL standard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808306/org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxexception-unexpected-token-near-li. you try this.
you should omit. select m

Comment: Looks like your `Member` class is not mapped. Show us your mapping configuration.

Comment: @talex What other mapping is needed besides the annotation of the Entity Class?

Comment: I suppose you use `Spring`. You should have `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` or something similar configured. look at this tutorial http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial

Comment: @talex No, I'm not using the Spring Framework. Web Application for Java EE Module.

Comment: Your `Persistence` class should configure `Hibernate` somehow. Check that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I did not know the cause, but I solved the problem. The problem is that the Entity Class must be declared in the package. If the entity class is declared in the default package, JPQL does not recognize it. If you know about the cause of the problem, I would appreciate your comments.

Answer (score -1):

```
TypedQuery<Member> query = em.createQuery("from Member");
```

you try it out. do not use select m clause.

Comment: The same exception occurs. :(

Comment: List<Member> result = (List<Member>) session.createQuery("from Member").list();

Comment: JPQL requires "SELECT m ", go check the JPA spec. You are suggesting that the user uses invalid JPA syntax (i.e Hibernate specific)